# javascript variables for individual elements passed into individual animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, animation

http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/uTV5k/14/

Hello,

I thought I was nearly their with this conundrum.

See my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/uTV5k/14/) live demo.

I've wrote some jQuery script for a fairly simple animation, but it's not working as I need it to.

The variable dimension that it's animating too, are all the same, I need those variables to be specific to the object as the text content is dynamic.

Image 1 - See below normal state...

[image]

Image 2 - Then see my hover state...

[image]

The Lorum Ipsum text title and excerpt are both dynamic - so will be variable heights, in the example above, it's a fairly long title, normally it will be two/three lines max. There will be about 9 boxes on a page, all with different length titles, so I'm trying to animate specific dimensions relative to the individual element.

See below my mark up that makes the box:

```
<div class="home-mod">

    <div class="mod-center"><img src="http://tintation.com/wp-content/uploads/amazing-images-graphics/star-wars-robo-robot.jpg" alt="" /></div>

    <div class="mod-info"> <!-- this is the slider, slides up when .mod-info is hovered -->

        <a href="http://jsfiddle.net/" title="testings" class="mod-link"><span>//</span> Proin consectetur velit sed nibh mollis nec facilisis orci convallis</a>

        <div class="mod-excerpt">

            Get the latest news and updates on your mobile device <a href="http://jsfiddle.net/" title="testings" >read more</a>

        </div>

    </div>   

</div>
```

Then see my script...

Which I've commented each action explaining what I'm doing.

```
    var moduleLink  = $("a.mod-link").innerHeight(),
    // I'm getting the dynamic height plus padding of a.modlink

    moduleInfo  = $("div.mod-info").height();
    // I'm getting the dynamic height of div.mod-info

$(".mod-info").css( "top" , "-" + moduleLink + "px" );
    // I'm adding css top position to the div.mod-info, this will make only the a.mod-link area visible

$("div.mod-info").hover(function() {
 // I'm selecting the div.mod-info box for a hover action

    $(this).animate({ top : "-" + moduleInfo + "px" });
    // Only this object will animate. I'm then animating to the specific var moduleInfo for this element

}, function() {

    $(this).animate({ top : "-" + moduleLink + "px" });
    // When un-hovering, it animates back to the top value of moduleLink height

});

$(".home-mod").click(function(){
// This is making the enitre .home-mod div a clickable div

    window.location=$(this).find("a.mod-link").attr("href");

    return false;         
});
```

Now even I can tell my script is dirty lol but could really help with some pro advice on either how to get my script to work as intended, or make the overall script less bloated, and work :-)

Really appreciate your time people.

See my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/uTV5k/14/) here, with multiple items to test.

Many Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/uTV5k/14/

Comment: Click on the "JSLint" button in jsFiddle. `$() {` structure on the first line isn't valid.

Comment: Syntax arror at `$(".home-mod") {` *what have you left half-finished ?*

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/uTV5k/8/ i've cleaned it up now - but you can see the variables it's getting are not specif to the individual element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try mine: http://jsfiddle.net/uTV5k/12/

Got it working

Had a little error there.. full code:

```
$(function() {


    $('.home-mod').each(function() {
        var moduleLink = $(this).find('.mod-link').innerHeight();
        $(this).find('.mod-info').css("top", "-" + moduleLink + "px");
    });

    $("div.mod-info").hover(function() {

        var moduleInfo = $(this).height();


        $(this).animate({
            top: "-" + moduleInfo + "px"
        });

    }, function() {

        var moduleLink = $(this).find('.mod-link').innerHeight();

        $(this).animate({
            top: "-" + moduleLink + "px"
        });

    });

    $(".home-mod").click(function() {

        window.location = $(this).find("a.mod-link").attr("href");

        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: You absolute beauty! Works perfect - whats the console.log bit mean, and have you wrapped it all in a function for a reason? So good dude, cannot thank you enough!!!

Comment: for debugging, you can remove those. If you like the answer would you be so kind to accept it? Many thanks man, and ofcourse..you're welcome :)

Comment: Also, you can just bind all these functions on page load. It's pretty efficient and makes the code look a bit cleaner.

Comment: nice one dude. thanks - though the .innerHeight I am using is having some unexpected results, not returning true height including padding until the animation is run, then it sorts itself out. Its fine in IE and Safari, but mozilla, and chrome it returns wrong height.

Comment: Though it works perfectly in the jsFiddle, just not on my site.

Comment: It's behaving so weird in different browers - not reading the correct height on initial load. Frustrating as it works fine in the jsFiddle :-( - I would share mysite with you but I don't want public to see, can I DM you some how?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5480/discussion-between-stephen-and-user801773)

Comment: Hey, if you're reading this pls drop your email address in the chat so we can fix this. I Think this is the correct solution.